# formatting text in user input fields

Tags: php, formatting

I have a customer who wishes to allow the customer to format text as it is entered into form fields such as italics, bold, buletted lists etc. These willl just be text boxes and text areas

It is my belief that this isn't possible (as the users dont know html to add formatting even if i could preserve it when writing to the db) unless you use one of those text element controls (http://jqueryte.com/demos) with the formatting optionsacross the top. It would look ludicrous havingone of those for a 10 one line text fields wouldnt it?

Or can you have the formattting bar at the top of the page and apply it to multiple input fields. Granted i have never seen that on any website

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use something simple like [richtextarea](http://richtextarea.thalmann.li/) and tweak it so the formatting controls only are visible while the textbox has focus.

Another option is to do what you stated, use a full blown rich text editor, but look for one that can be restricted and preferably hides the controls whil not focused, one example is [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/inline.php). It should ofcourse only load the whole editor code once, and be able to apply to multiple fields on a page.

Another lightweight one is [CLEeditor](https://github.com/cleditor/cleditor), but it seems to be fading away. It was capable of using the standard keystrokes Ctrl-B for **Bold** and Ctrl-I for *italic* without having the toolbar visible (however it may not work in all browsers any more since it has not been updated in ages).